# How to get file from an already loaded source?

Tags: javascript, html, file, video, gif

I'm trying to access a gif file from an **already loaded** `source` to read it's meta data
(by using the console in devTools)

The html is as such:

```
<video>
 <source src="https://somesite.com/somegif.gif?format=mp4">
</video>
```

and I already have a function which reads and prints the meta data but it takes [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) data type as an argument:

```
function gifMetadata(file){
  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  ...
}
```

so how do I get `file` from `source` without having to `fetch()` the data again?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised that if you fetch again it will load the cached file.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm uncertain of that so I'm playing it safe by directly reading the data already received, I just don't know how

Comment: @cakelover You have to do it the other way round... (1) Load file bytes via Fetch. (2) Play same loaded bytes in a `<video>` tag. To play, you create [a blob URL](https://gist.github.com/edin-m/889fa79a0fa124b1a8c3) from array buffer of bytes (not File object)... What metadata do you need from the MP4? If it's basic like width/height, then just read them directly from the `<video>` object without using Fetch.

Comment: @VC.One I don't think that will be possible, I'm using devTools hence I can't use `Fetch` and instead I'll have to work with the data already loaded into the site. I'm trying to get the duration of the GIF as shown in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I'm trying to access a gif file from an **already loaded** source to read it's meta data
>
> (by using the console in devTools)"*

You **cannot access** bytes of content loaded in a media element.
You could try reading the `.duration` property, if the server is returning data in MP4 format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
<source src="https://somesite.com/somegif.gif?format=mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>

var duration = -1;
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

vid.onloadedmetadata = function(){ get_Duration() };

function get_Duration()
{
    duration = vid.duration;
    //alert("duration (secs) : " + duration);
    console.log("duration (secs) : " + duration);
}

</script> 

</body> 
</html>
```